# Oracle 19c create table result_cache clause syntax

Tags: oracle, cache, oracle-19c

I could not find the exact syntax for the "Result_Cache" clause in the [Oracle 19c documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6:%7E:text=part%20of%20LOB_parameters-,RESULT_CACHE%20Clause,-Use%20this%20clause) for the `CREATE TABLE` statement.  It mentions the values of `DEFAULT` or `FORCE`, but not the syntax.  Same issue for the ALTER TABLE statement.  What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation, and some almost useful error messages, I was able to do this:

```
alter table SCOTT.EMP result_cache (mode force);
```

The RESULT_CACHE_Clause (note the underscores everywhere) is [documented in Oracle 21c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6:%7E:text=part%20of%20LOB_parameters-,result_cache_clause,-Use%20this%20clause), along with the additional new settings for 21c.